# How to make required form validation using Angular and FormBuilder

Tags: angular

I've been coding in angular, this is my first time working with material and form groups, and for the life of me I can't figure out how to add required validators. I've been following there https://angular.io/guide/form-validation, and I also tried https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview, But neither of them are working. Here's my code for the html file:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
     <mat-label>Alert</mat-label>
     <input matInput id="name" formcontrolname="alert" placeholder="Ex. Red" accept=".pdf" required>
     <div *ngIf="(alert.dirty || alert.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
          <div *ngIf="alert.errors?.['required']">
               Name is required
          </div>
     </div>
</mat-form-field>
```

And heres the code for the component file:

```
export class ReportUploadFormComponent {
  uploadFileForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    this.uploadFileForm = this.fb.group({
      patientId: ['', [Validators.required]],
      type: ['', [Validators.required]],
      device: ['', [Validators.required]],
      fieldLine: ['', [Validators.required]],
      serviceLine: ['', [Validators.required]],
      alert: ['', [Validators.required]]
    })

  }

  @Output() reportUploadForm: EventEmitter<ReportUploadOutput> = new EventEmitter();

  public uploadFile() {

    const outputValue: ReportUploadOutput = this.uploadFileForm.value;

    this.reportUploadForm.emit(outputValue);
  }

  get alert() { return this.uploadFileForm.get('alert'); }
  get type() { return this.uploadFileForm.get('type'); }
  get patientId() { return this.uploadFileForm.get('patientId'); }
  get fieldLine() { return this.uploadFileForm.get('fieldLine'); }
  get device() { return this.uploadFileForm.get('device'); }
  get serviceLine() { return this.uploadFileForm.get('serviceLine'); }
```

But no matter what, the error is not showing up even when I try to submit the alert field as empty. What am I doing wrong?

I also looked at this issue but it didn't work either [How to set a custom error message to a form in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000152/how-to-set-a-custom-error-message-to-a-form-in-angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo (?), `formcontrolname="..."` should be...

```
 formControlName="..."
```

Notice the capital `C` and `N`. Also just a sidenote, I like to use `hasError` for showing errors, so in this case I would do:

```
*ngIf="alert.hasError('required')"
```

Comment: Well now I feel like an idiot. Thanks! This works great, and I tried the has error as well